# What do the different line types mean in Google Maps' Schedule Explorer?

Tags: google-maps

[image: Screenshot]

In the above screenshot, which is about getting from 1 Tsing Yi Road, Hong Kong to Hong Kong Airport, I understand the solid blue lines mean a bus, and the solid green line means the MTR, and blue circles represent walking, but what do the diagonal stripes mean?

Comment: i think it means you have to travel inside a station but i am guessing. i

Comment: @JordanReiser It's best to have answers that you can back up via references.  Guessing won't really help anyone who comes across this question in the future.

Comment: Locked as obsolete because Google Maps Schedule Explorer is no longer available.

Answer (score 0):

It is the waiting period between the rides